# Maven 1.0 snapshot .jar cannot find class name

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, cmd, snapshot

I wrote maven project and it run correctly in Eclipse but  I want to run maven project in cmd line so I write this line in cmd 
java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.my.App 
I have this error

> Could not find or load main class com.my.App

How I solved it?

Comment: please provide more information. Looks like the class `com.my.App` was not part of the jar file... try using `jar -tvf target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` command to check if the class file is indeed present in the jar file

Comment: @uthavaakkarai my class name is indeed in teh jar file but I still same error.I tried  java -jar -Dapple.awt.UIElement="true" target/myAppName-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -h but I had same error.  In pom.xml  packetname.classname in mainclass tag and in correct ..How I solve it? Can you help me?

Comment: It looks like you've posted this question twice. Perhaps you should close this question and focus on the other one.